# Move files of specific size in Ubuntu using Terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to move all the files in a specific folder having size of 0 bytes. I know that the following prints all the files with size zero bytes.

```
find /home/Desktop/ -size  0
```

But i want to move them to another folder, so i tried :

```
find /home/Desktop/ -size  0 | xargs -0 mv /home/Desktop/a
```

But that doesn't work. ? Is there any other way to do it.? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in find itself using `-exec` option:

```
find /home/Desktop/ -size 0 -exec mv '{}' /home/Desktop/a \;
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` default prints the file name on the standard output followed by a newline. The option `-print0` prints the file name followed by a null character instead. The option `-0` of `xargs` means that the input is terminated by a null character.

```
find /home/Desktop/ -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /home/Desktop/a
```

You could instead use `find`'s option `-exec`

In both cases consider also using `find`'s option `-type f` if you only want to find files and the option `-maxdepth 1` if you do not want find to descend directories. This is specially usefull in your example since you move the found files to a subdirectory!